# Terraform | AWS ECS service | desired count value changes for every tf apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

When I do `terraform apply` every time the desired count is changing from 1 -> 2. Please suggest.
But in `variables.tf`, I declared as `desired_count=2`.

```
~ resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs_service" {
         cluster                            = "arn:aws:ecs::cluster/"
         deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
         deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 100
       ~ desired_count                      = 1 -> 2
         enable_ecs_managed_tags            = false
         force_new_deployment               = true
         health_check_grace_period_seconds  = 0
         iam_role                           = "aws-service-role"
         id                                 = "arn:aws:ecs:-ecs-service"
         launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
         name                               = "ecs-service"
         platform_version                   = "LATEST"
         propagate_tags                     = "NONE"
         scheduling_strategy                = "REPLICA"
         tags                               = {}
         task_definition                    = "arn:aws:ecs:"
         deployment_controller {
             type = "ECS"
         }
         load_balancer {
             container_name   = "abcd"
             container_port   = 80
             target_group_arn = "arn.*"
         }
         network_configuration {
             assign_public_ip = false
             security_groups  = []
             subnets          = []
         }
     }
```

Here is the main.tf:- 
**Note**:- I am using modules to invoke main.tf.

```
############ ECS Service ##############
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs_service" {
  name                 = "${var.name}-ecs-service"
  cluster              = var.cluster_id
  task_definition      = var.task_definition_arn
  desired_count        = var.desired_count
  iam_role             = var.ecs_iam_role
  force_new_deployment = var.force_new_deployment
  launch_type          = "FARGATE"
  deployment_controller {
    type = "ECS"
  }
  deployment_maximum_percent         = "200"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = "100"
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = var.lb_tg_arn
    container_name   = var.name
    container_port   = var.port
  }
  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = var.security_group_id
    subnets          = var.subnets
    assign_public_ip = var.assign_public_ip
  }
  depends_on = [var.aws_alb]
}
```

Variables are assigned on the requirement of my project by making default=null

Comment: Where is your actual code?

Comment: Do you run anything else apart from terraform that might be also making changes to the service?

Comment: As a simple thing to check, have a look at the tfstate file after applying, and see if it says 1 or 2

Comment: Show your variables.tf and main.tf please

Comment: Have you specified tf backend to store tf state, or store it locally?

Comment: @VadimYangunaev I have added main.tf

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what is really causing the change, but if you only want to mute the change you can go with ignoring the change as described in the [terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_service.html)

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "example" {
  # ... other configurations ...

  # Example: Create service with 2 instances to start
  desired_count = 2

  # Optional: Allow external changes without Terraform plan difference
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [desired_count]
  }
}
```

Comment: since terraform >0.12... more appropriate is `ignore_changes = [desired_count]` - skip quotations in desired_count